# Transform XML using API & XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, api, xslt

I am trying to write a API Post method that can take a large XML as a argument and transform it using a XSLT file and return the response.

What I have tried.

```
public string Post([FromBody]string xml)
{
    string status = string.Empty;
    string tempxmlFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    status= appyStyeSheet(xml, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ @"Contents\Xml_to_Xpath.xslt", tempxmlFileName);
    return status;

}


public string appyStyeSheet(string rowxml, string xslt, string cbxml)
    {

        string status = string.Empty;
        if (rowxml != "")
        {

            try
            {
                using (StringReader sReader = new StringReader(rowxml))
                using (XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader))
                using (XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(cbxml))
                {
                    XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslTransform.Load(xslt);
                   xslTransform.Transform(xReader, xWriter);

                }
                status = "success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { status = ex.Message; }

        }
        else
        {
            status = "null";
        }
        return rowxml;
    }
```

Problems:

1. Not able to use XML without using serialization. i.e I don't want use any classes because XML size is very large.
2. with the form body and string variable i am not able to fetch XML content. It is always coming null.

Comment: The Load method want a stream and you are giving it a string xslt.  Use StringReader reader = new StringReader(xslt); xslTransform.Load(reader);  The using method will close the stream after the {}.

Comment: @jdweng the first problem is how to get XML without serialization on post request in the above example I am using string datatype but it is not working.

Comment: You can use the XmlWriter.WriteRaw(string) which will take xml as a string and write to output.

Comment: Did you mean  public string Post([FromBody]XmlWriter.WriteRaw(string) xml) like this.

Comment: You only have a piece of you code so I'm assuming the XmlWriter is somehow connected to your http write stream.  The xml writer will take an XML string and write.  You do not need the XmlWriter if you already have an XML string.  The string can be the body of you http post.